# Nested IF-FOR-IF loops

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck in nested loops.
`this.isRyt` is a variable where a retrived string from JSON is stored.
`i` is a user input variable of type string.
`this.storeArray[]` is an array where every input of `i` from user will be stored only if it matches the string stored in `this.isRyt` variable.So basically I want to compare the strings stored in `this.storeArray[]` by using index `k` to the string stored in `this.isRryt`(as multiple `i` inputs from user will stored at different index locations in `this.storeArray[]`),and if the string is **not** matched then there is variable `counter` which will get incremented.`incCounter` is nothing but a simple counter variable initialized with value 0.

My try: I tried using the below loop ,  but `this.counter++` get incremented multiple times in a single time(multiple iterations of `k`) as it is inside the for loop. I want to make it increment only a single time but the *for* condition should not be omitted.

```
filterAnswer(i:any) //Comparing Answer submitted by user with JSON answer
      {


         this.isRyt = this.questArrayNew1[0].isRight;
         if(this.isRyt == i )
        {


           for(let k = 0 ; k < this.questArray.length ; k++)
            {

            if(this.storeArray[k] == i)
            {   
              console.log(k);
            }
            else
            {
              this.counter++; //WANT TO INCREMENT ONLY ONE TIME IF IT DOESNT SATISFY THE CONDITION FOR WHOLE K=0,1,2,3.. variable
            } 

           }

            this.storeArray[this.incCounter] = i ;
            console.log(this.storeArray);
            this.incCounter++;

        }
        else
        {
          return 0;
        }

      }
```

Comment: I really suggest that you learn the basics of control structures, and also JavaScript. If you don't know how to use loops and variables you certainly shouldn't even consider using classes.

Comment: Thanks Aluan! I'll surely look into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, this.counter only needs to be incremented once.  You could try something like this:

```
filterAnswer(i:any) //Comparing Answer submitted by user with JSON answer
  {
     var notCounted = true; //condition for this.counter++ code block to be executed
     this.isRyt = this.questArrayNew1[0].isRight;

     if(this.isRyt == i )
      {

       for(let k = 0 ; k < this.questArray.length ; k++)
        {
          if(this.storeArray[k] == i)
           {   
             console.log(k);
           }
        else
           {
             while(notCounted)
              { //executes while bool is true
               this.counter++; 
               notCounted = false; //incremented so now no longer needed
              }
           } 
        }

        this.storeArray[this.incCounter] = i ;
        console.log(this.storeArray);
        this.incCounter++;

    }
    else
     {
      return 0;
     }

  }
```